# How do I assign a position in a list to a string based on its trinary value?

Tags: python, graph-theory, combinatorics

I'm writing a program to construct a directed graph, the nodes of which will be 3-letter strings that are elements of the set of all possible combinations of the letters: 'Q','W', and 'E' (ex., one node would contain 'WEW' and another 'EWW').

Each combination will be represented only once for a total of 27 nodes. Each node will have 3 edges that connect it to the three other combinations that it can be transformed into by pushing a 'Q', 'W', or 'E' from the right and popping the leftmost letter (ex., 'QQW' would have directed edges towards 'QWQ','QWW', and 'QWE').

In order to implement this I had the idea of using Python dictionaries and thought that a clever way to decide which string goes with which node would be to use a trinary number system where 'Q' = 0, 'W' = 1, and 'E' = 2. This way there would be a logical ordering to the nodes and I could use a loop to do the assignation instead of having to base my program on a massive 81-element dictionary (ex., key = 'QQW', value = ['QWE','QWQ','QWW'] repeated for all 27 combinations) that I had to hard-code.

How would I go about using the idea of the trinary number system to accomplish this task in a way that wasn't just me coding in: 'QQQ' = 0, 'QQW' = 1, 'QQE' = 2, etc.? In other words, how do I tell the program that 'Q' = 0, 'W' = 1, 'E' = 2 so that in a for loop I can say something simple like:

```
for i in 0:26
list[i] = "appropriate string corresponding to the trinary value of i"
```

Thanks!

Comment: IIUC, just use dictionaries to map the alphabets to numbers and vice versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the last position is worth `1*char_value` where char_value is 0 for Q, 1 for W and 2 for E. The middle position is worth `3*char_value` and the first `9*char_value`. In general `3**i * char_value` where `i` is the position counted from the right (`3**i` is 3 to the power of i).

```
def triple_value(triple):
    char_value = {
        'Q': 0,
        'W': 1,
        'E': 2}

    return sum(3**i * char_value[c]
               for i, c in enumerate(reversed(triple)))

for t in ['QQQ', 'QQW', 'EEW', 'EEE']:
    print(t, triple_value(t))
```

---

```
QQQ 0
QQW 1
EEW 25
EEE 26
```